# CGAffineTransformMakeScale parameter values

Tags: ios, decimal, scale

It seems like CGAffineTransformMakeScale only works with values with 1 decimal.

All these works

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6);
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2);
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.6, 2.3);
```

The app crash if i try to scale with these

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.62, 0.62);
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.23, 0.23);
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.61, 2.31);
```

It this how its suppose to work?

Comment: Can you paste the crash log? This is definitely interesting

Comment: They shouldn't cause any crash. Providing crash log would definitely be helpful.